# Is there a reliable selector that can select elements based on styles?

Tags: css, queryselector

Here is a function I have written. It works well to get the closest element that has a certain attribute:

```
// Example of attribute if id

export function getClosestAttribute(
  element: SVGElement,
  attribute: keyof typeof svgAttributeToCssStyle,
  excludeElement: boolean
): string | null {
  let firstIncludedEl: Element | null = element;
  if (excludeElement) {
    firstIncludedEl = element.parentElement;
  }
  if (!firstIncludedEl) {
    return null;
  }
  const closestEl = firstIncludedEl.closest(`[${attribute}]`);
  if (!closestEl) {
    return null;
  }

  return closestEl.getAttribute(attribute);
}
```

Is it possible to write something similar for styles? E.g. I want to select any elements that have `style="...fill:..."`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

Another approach is to match two rules. The first "start with" rule matches: `color: red`, but not `background-color: red`.

```
div[style^="color:"] {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

The second rule matches when the string occurs anywhere later in the `style` value:

```
div[style*=" color:"] {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Then we just chain them together:

```css
div[style^="color:"],
div[style*=" color:"] {
  text-decoration: underline;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: red;">Should not match
</div>

<div style="font-size: 20px; color: red;">Match
</div>

<div style="color: red; font-size: 32px;">Match
</div>

<div style="font-size: 20px; background-color: red;">Should not match
</div>
```

__

You could use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and look for a `style` value that contained a string of your choosing. However, white space matters. If you're looking for `style*="color: red"` but your `style` value has no space between `color:` and `red`, the selector will *not* find matches.

> [attr*=value]
> Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value contains at least one occurrence of value within the string.

Example:

```css
div[style*="color: red"] {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div style="color: blue;">Regular div
</div>

<div style="color: red;">Add an underline
</div>
```

Comment: I want to catch all elements that have a certain style attribute. Your method is a good suggestion, but unfortunately it also matches background-color, which is a different style attribute, see: https://jsfiddle.net/npLbcjao/

Comment: @user1283776 I've updated my answer and filtered out the false positives.

Comment: That's a good idea! I added another rule to your solution to make it more reliable: https://jsfiddle.net/npLbcjao/2/. I can't come up with any examples that it does not catch now. I will think some more and intend to accept your solution later. Thanks!

Comment: @user1283776 I like the semi-colon addition you made. Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
div[style^="color: red"] {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This works if style attribute starts with *color: red*.